# In the ASP.net Web project, when I used the TextBox control, I couldn't switch the Chinese input method

Tags: c#, asp.net

eg:

```html
 <td style="width:26px;height:30px;">
   <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="城市" Font-Size="9pt" >
   </asp:Label>
 </td>
 <td style="width:133px;height:30px">
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
```

When I input English,It can works normally.But when I switch the Chinese,the browser flashes back, so I can't get the Chinese data by TextBox.

Comment: What do you mean "flashes back"? Is that the string successfully retrieved from code-behind?

Comment: "flashes back" means the browser exit.